# How to copy a linked table in MS Access 2007 to local table with VBA (or C#)?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2007 database, `c:\myDb.accdb`, with a table named `MASTER_TABLE` that is linked to a table named `TBL.MASTER_TABLE` in a DB2 database named `PRODUCTION`.

When I open `MASTER_TABLE`, I'm prompted for my login credentials for the `PRODUCTION` database.

I wrote an app in C# that uses the `MASTER_TABLE` table, but of course it prompts the user for a login. To circumvent that, I need to copy the linked table to an existing local table named `LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE` in `myDb.accdb`.

This copy needs to be automated, so the username/password needs to be passed programmatically instead of raising a prompt.

In Access, I tried the following to create a local copy, but it doesn't capture if a field is indexed:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC; DSN=PRODUCTION; UID=username; PWD=password; LANGUAGE=us_english; Database=PRODUCTION", acTable, "TBL.MASTER_TABLE", "LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE"
```

I also tried this: [How to copy a linked table to a local table in Ms Access programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594096/how-to-copy-a-linked-table-to-a-local-table-in-ms-access-programmatically)

But I get an error `3001: Arguements are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another`

I'm calling the `CopySchemaAndData_ADOX` function with the following:

`Call CopySchemaAndData_ADOX(TBL.MASTER_TABLE, LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE)`

Anyway, can anyone think of a way to do this in either VBA or possibly in C#? Or why I'm getting the error in the code I tried to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *"make table"* query in an Access session.

```
SELECT *
INTO LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE
FROM MASTER_TABLE;
```

You may need to provide your credentials when you execute that query.

Since `MASTER_TABLE` is a working linked table, `LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE` will be created with Access-compatible field types.

Turns out that suggestion is not appropriate because you want to automate the import and avoid asking the user for DB2 credentials each time.

However you do have `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` working except that it doesn't pull in the index.  So I'll suggest you do the `TransferDatabase` and then follow up by executing a [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177891%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that prompts me to log into the PRODUCTION database. Is there a way to pass the credentials? I did this: `Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * INTO LOCAL_MASTER_TABLE FROM MASTER_TABLE"
CurrentDb.Execute sql`. Also, will it copy if a field is indexed or not?

Comment: I need to avoid the login prompt so I can automate this later

Comment: The table needs to be updated twice a week. Normally for something like this, I create a form in Access and set it to open when the DB opens, and put the VBA in the `On_Load` event. Then I create a task with Windows Task Scheduler to open the .accdb file at 3am or whenever.

Comment: I'm fumbling here, Jeff.  If the `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` in your question made a local table, but its only shortcoming was it didn't include the index ... why not just follow `TransferDatabase` with a `CREATE INDEX ...`?

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to end up doing. I didn't know `CREATE INDEX` was a thing .. but it sounds like that's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: hello guys.. i need to use same above query for make table without data from master table.i need to use only columns from master table. can anybody help me