# Copy Access 2013 linked table to local table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

All comboboxes on the form query the same SQL Server table as RowSource. This causes significant performance issues because the RowSource query is run once for each combobox.

What is the best way to improve performance? Is there a way to cache table results or should it write to a local table on form open?

Comment: [I have found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594096/how-to-copy-a-linked-table-to-a-local-table-in-ms-access-programmatically) as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a linked table to a local table in Ms Access programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594096/how-to-copy-a-linked-table-to-a-local-table-in-ms-access-programmatically)

Comment: @Sami No, my question is different. I would like to know what is the best solution for my problem.

Comment: How many combo boxes on the same form are referencing the same SQL Server table as the RowSource and how many rows of data are being returned to the combo box list from the SQL Server table? Unless there are extreme numbers involved in either part of the answer, I'm puzzled about why there would be a performance problem.

Comment: @JohnMo Upwards of 70.

Comment: All tables can be queried individually in under 5 seconds. This is why I suspect the comboboxes are causing the problem.

Comment: Loading 70 combo boxes is a big deal no matter where the data comes from. How many rows of data are going into each combo box? Is each combo box a subset of the source table so that there's a WHERE condition applied for each combo box?

Comment: @JohnMo The RowSource is 3-4 rows from a larger table. The form writes one row at a time.